# #Updating Registry Permissions

Tags: powershell, permissions, registry

## Updating Registry Permissions

```
$RegistryAcl = Get-Acl "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\LynxGate"
$RuleObject = @{
TypeName = "system.security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule"(
ArgumentList = “CATApplication","FullControl","Allow")
}
$RegistryRule = New-Object $RuleObject
$RegistryAcl.SetAccessRule ($RegistryRule)
$RegistryAcl | Set-Acl -path $RegistryAcl.path
}
```

Im getting a problem with my powershell script, can anyone give some insight on my issue.  Im trying to add a new user called CATApplication with Full Access to premissions. But im getting a error.

Comment: What problem? I'm not a mind reader.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you forgot to ask a question, Chris. However, I see a problem here:

```
$RegistryRule = New-Object $RuleObject
```

should be

```
$RegistryRule = New-Object @RuleObject
```

as it looks like you mean to splat the hashtable to new-object.

Comment: Well, you need to supply a type.  `$RegistryRule = New-Object PSObject -Property @RuleObject`